# How to put button in line with the bottom of the "Discounts" div?

Tags: html, vertical-alignment

[image: I'm trying to get the button to look like the picture]

I'm just learning how forms, inputs, and fieldsets are working, so I'm trying to make replicate the image above with my own code. So far, I have been able to figure out most of it, but I don't know how to properly put the button in line with the bottom of the third div. I tried a span tag with vertical-align: bottom, but that did not work. Also, I tried to make a div and use vertical-align bottom, which didn't work either. I think I just have a poor understanding of vertical-align, so if you could help it would be greatly appreciated.

```html
 <body style="background-color:#EEEEEE">
    
    <form name="data" action="https://www.hats.com" method="POST">
        <fieldset style="width: 750px;">
            <legend>Ordering Information</legend>
            First Name: <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="Joey" size="25">
            &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Last Name: <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Shmoey" size="25">
            <br> <br> Street Address: <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="1234 Sesame Street" size="30">
            State: <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="PA" maxlength="2" size="2">
            City: <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="York">
            Zip:<input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="17402" maxlength="5" size="8">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset style="width: 750px;">
            <legend>Payment and Shipping</legend>
            <div style="width: 250px; float: left;">Payment:<br>
            <input type="radio" name="payment" value="Visa">Visa<br>
            <input type="radio" name="payment" value="MasterCard">MasterCard<br>
            <input type="radio" name="payment" value="Paypal">Paypal</div>
            <div style="width: 250px; float: left;"> Shipping:<br>
            <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="Priority $7.99">Priority %7.99<br>
            <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="Standard $3.99">Standard $3.99<br>
            <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="Overnight $15.99">Overnight $15.99</div>
            <div style="float: left;">Discounts:<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="discounts" value="AAA">AAA<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="discounts" value="AARP">AARP<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="discounts" value="Haltz Member">Hatz Member</div>
            <a href="https://www.hats.com/" target="_blank" title="Hat Store"><button type="button">Join Now!</button></a>      
        </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Putting a `button` inside an `a` tag is invalid HTML. See the Permitted Content section : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 1):

3 issues:

1: you were missing a " on your body tag

2: when you use float:left you take the element out of the flow of the dom.  In this case it's better to use display:inline-block

3: add display:block, margin-left:  your a tag

NOTE: your form looks pretty good.

```css
a{
display:inline-block;
margin-left:10px;

}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:#EEEEEE">
    
    <form name="data" action="https://www.hats.com" method="POST">
        <fieldset style="width: 750px;">
            <legend>Ordering Information</legend>
            First Name: <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="Joey" size="25">
            &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Last Name: <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Shmoey" size="25">
            <br> <br> Street Address: <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="1234 Sesame Street" size="30">
            State: <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="PA" maxlength="2" size="2">
            City: <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="York">
            Zip:<input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="17402" maxlength="5" size="8">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset style="width: 750px;">
            <legend>Payment and Shipping</legend>
            <div style="width: 250px; float: left;">Payment:<br>
            <input type="radio" name="payment" value="Visa">Visa<br>
            <input type="radio" name="payment" value="MasterCard">MasterCard<br>
            <input type="radio" name="payment" value="Paypal">Paypal</div>
            <div style="width: 250px; float: left;"> Shipping:<br>
            <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="Priority $7.99">Priority %7.99<br>
            <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="Standard $3.99">Standard $3.99<br>
            <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="Overnight $15.99">Overnight $15.99</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block;">Discounts:<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="discounts" value="AAA">AAA<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="discounts" value="AARP">AARP<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="discounts" value="Haltz Member">Hatz Member</div>
            
            <a  href="https://www.hats.com/" target="_blank" title="Hat Store"><button type="button">Join Now!</button></a>      
        </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
```

But a better way is to use flex:

```css
#container{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-around;
align-items:bottom;
align-items:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:#EEEEEE">
        
        <form name="data" action="https://www.hats.com" method="POST">
            <fieldset style="width: 750px;">
                <legend>Ordering Information</legend>
                First Name: <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="Joey" size="25">
                &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Last Name: <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Shmoey" size="25">
                <br> <br> Street Address: <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="1234 Sesame Street" size="30">
                State: <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="PA" maxlength="2" size="2">
                City: <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="York">
                Zip:<input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="17402" maxlength="5" size="8">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset style="width: 750px;">
                <legend>Payment and Shipping</legend>
                <div id='container'>
                <div >Payment:<br>
                <input type="radio" name="payment" value="Visa">Visa<br>
                <input type="radio" name="payment" value="MasterCard">MasterCard<br>
                <input type="radio" name="payment" value="Paypal">Paypal</div>
                <div > Shipping:<br>
                <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="Priority $7.99">Priority %7.99<br>
                <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="Standard $3.99">Standard $3.99<br>
                <input type="radio" name="shipping" value="Overnight $15.99">Overnight $15.99</div>
                <div> Discounts:<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="discounts" value="AAA">AAA<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="discounts" value="AARP">AARP<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="discounts" value="Haltz Member">Hatz Member</div>
                
                
                <a  href="https://www.hats.com/" target="_blank" title="Hat Store"><button type="button">Join Now!</button></a>   </div>   
            </fieldset>
    </form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `label` tags here for all your field label.

Each radio button list should also bee in it's own `fieldset`

Also don't use tags like `br` or elements like `&nbsp;` for spacing, user `margin` or `padding` instead.

Let's now encapsulate the radio buttons and the labels in a label tag. That will help up align the link. Don't use a button in a link, it's invalid HTML and can result in odd behavior. Instead, style the link appropriately, I'd keep it looking like a link as it is an actual link to an external site opening in a new tab.

```css
body {
  background-color: #EEEEEE
}

.flex {
  display:flex;
}

label.wide {
  padding-right: 1em;
}

label {
  white-space:nowrap;
  padding-bottom:0.5em;
  display:inline-block;
}



fieldset fieldset {
  border: none;
  padding-bottom:0;
}

#paymentShippingFields fieldset label {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom:0;
}

#paymentShippingFields fieldset {
  border:none;
  width:33%;
}
```

```html
<form name="data" action="https://www.hats.com" method="POST">
  <fieldset style="width: 750px;">
    <legend>Ordering Information</legend>
    <fieldset id="nameField">
      <label class="wide">First Name: <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="Joey" size="25"></label>
      <label>Last Name: <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Shmoey" size="25"></label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="addressField">
      <label>Street Address: <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="1234 Sesame Street" size="30"></label>
      <label>State: <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="PA" maxlength="2" size="2"></label>
      <label>City: <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="York"></label>
      <label>Zip:  <input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="17402" maxlength="5" size="8"></label>

    </fieldset>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset style="width: 750px;" id="paymentShippingFields">
    <legend>Payment and Shipping</legend>
    <div class="flex">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Payment:</legend>
        <label><input type="radio" name="payment" value="Visa">Visa</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="payment" value="MasterCard">MasterCard</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="payment" value="Paypal">Paypal</label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Shipping:</legend>
          <label><input type="radio" name="shipping" value="Priority $7.99">Priority %7.99</label>
          <label><input type="radio" name="shipping" value="Standard $3.99">Standard $3.99</label>
          <label><input type="radio" name="shipping" value="Overnight $15.99">Overnight $15.99</label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Discounts:</legend>
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="discounts" value="AAA">AAA</label>
          <label><input type="checkbox" name="discounts" value="AARP">AARP</label>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="discounts" value="Haltz Member">Hatz Member
            <a href="https://www.hats.com/" target="_blank" title="Hat Store">Join Now!</a>
          </label>
       </fieldset>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```